AWS Beanstalk Postgres RDS The connection attempt failed
While deploying a spring boot application with the following application.yml properties with actaul values, I get the below errors. Local postgres db instance works fine, getting the issue only with AWS.
RDS status shows Available.

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
and
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<aws-endpoint>:5432/<dbname>
    username: <dbusername>
    password: <dbpassword>
    
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 200000
      maximumPoolSize: 5
      
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Error:
HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:279)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:193)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:69)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:231)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:199)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1383)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1454)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at com.kyn.tot.invoice.web.TotalInvoiceWebApplication.main(TotalInvoiceWebApplication.java:33)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:551)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011... 58 common frames omitted
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #033[30m2024-06-30 16:31:49,026#033[0;39m #033[31mWARN #033[0;39m [#033[34mmain#033[0;39m] #033[33mJdbcEnvironmentInitiator#033[0;39m: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:279)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:193)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:69)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:231)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:199)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1383)
Jun 30 16:31:49 ip-10-241-152-170 web[352074]: #011at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1454)


"Connect timed out": a network (configuration) problem, not a software development question.

RDS, Beanstalk and EC2 are part of VPN and DB doesn't have public access. Is it possible to  find specific connectivity issues using CloudShell? Please let me know how to debug this issue.
